# c++ 11 class initialize error

Tags: c++11, memory

why `BASE *base_0 = new BASE(); //error?`  does it allocate memory when the class is defined?

```
class BASE {

public:
     int *i = new int(5);                              
     BASE *base_0 = new BASE();      
     static const BASE base_1;       
     static BASE base_2;             
    ~BASE() {
     cout << "~";
    }

};
```

Comment: um what? won't creating a `BASE` create another `BASE` via `new` and therefore create another `BASE` and another `BASE` forever? what's the use case here?

Comment: Can you provide the error you got from the compiler?

Comment: synthesized method 'constexpr BASE::BASE()' first required here |

Comment: @vu1p3n0x   u are right. but i don't create a object,so we don't care that question. i just define the class, it should not allocate memory, why it also error?  and if i overwrite  BASE() {}  ,that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different compilers will give you different errors:

```
struct S {
    S* s = new S();
};
```

under the right version of GCC produces:

```
prog.cpp:2:15: error: constructor required before non-static data member for 'S::s' has been parsed
  S* s = new S();
               ^
```

http://ideone.com/8TU5Th

Even though you are not actually calling `new` at this point, the compiler needs to *parse* the `new` call. Because you are not supplying a default ctor, it has to synthesize one, but it can't do this because this member references `new` which references the default ctor, so until this statement has been fully processed it can't know how to generate the ctor.

Also, you say that "I don't create any object of BASE" in your comments on another answer, but in-fact you do:

```
 static const BASE base_1;       
 static BASE base_2;
```

both of these statements will require the program to default-initialize an instance of BASE at startup, and the first thing that instance of BASE will do is allocate a dynamic instance of BASE and call it's constructor, which will ...

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the constructor and it is trying to fill in the new BASE() before a default constructor is created. That is the `constexpr BASE::BASE()` error you're receiving. Adding the `BASE::BASE()` constructor anywhere in your class should fix the issue.

For initializing pointers, you may wish to also do that in the constructor.

```
class BASE 
{

public:
  BASE()
  {
    std::cout << "c";
    i = new int(5);
    base_0 = new BASE();
  }
  ~BASE()
  {
    std::cout << "~";
  }

  int *i;                              
  BASE *base_0;
  static const BASE base_1;       
  static BASE base_2;                   
};
```

Although the use for this us unknown to me. When instantiating a new `BASE` it also compiles the constructor. This happens every time a new class is instantiated, so when you instantiate a new `BASE` class inside the `BASE` constructor you're going to instantiate new `BASE` classes until you run out of memory.

Essentially this is a fork bomb.

Comment: thank you for anwser, but i don't create any object of BASE, the define should not  allocate memory.  i just define a class like this, and compile error :synthesized method 'constexpr BASE::BASE()' first required here ,  i found that if  i overwrite the BASE() {} , there are no error, of course if i use this class's object ,what you said maybe happen, but i just want to know ,why i just define this ,compile also has error?  thank you!

Comment: Think about this: The "synthesized method" is the constructor "constexpr BASE::BASE()". The compiler is looking at the line `BASE* base_0 = new BASE()` and trying to find the `BASE::BASE()` constructor before it synthesizes it.